# how to use ajax methods in content pages

Tags: c#, ajax

I am having a problem in using Ajax methods.I have a master page and a content page.I want to use Ajax methods in content page.For that

in cs page in page load:

```
Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(testcontent));
```

i have added this as my content page name is testcontent.

This is my method in cs page :

```
 [Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
  public int Getdatabyid(int id)
  {
        int count  = 0 ;
       //getting the id and basing on that processing the data and assigning to count
        return count;
  }
```

in my aspx page :

```
function getdata(value)
{
 var id = value;
  var count = testcontent.Getdatabyid(id);
}
```

But i am getting the error "testcontent unavailable".
Can i use Ajax methods in Content Pages which inherits properties from master page.In master page i placed Script Manager...Pls help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for the question.

In web.config file,

add these lines of code.

```
 <system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory,Ajax"/>
   </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
```

This will allow the Ajax Methods.